# Javascript validation issue?

Tags: javascript, function, validation

I have a function written to validate a form where a phone number must be entered. What i am trying to make it do is that if there is a number entered it makes sure that the number is in the correct format, meaning that the field is not mandatory. The problem i am having is that if the field is left empty (which is acceptable) it still alerts with the message "That is not correct telephone number format" when instead it should just not validate the field at all, if it is empty. Here is the code i am using:

```
function validateHome() {
    var num2 = document.getElementById('homeno').value;

    if (num2 !== "" && !num2.match(/\(\d{2}\)\d{8}/)) {
        alert('That is not correct telephone number format');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Could anyone help me with pointing out my mistakes?

Comment: What is the value of `num2` when it's alerting but shouldn't?

Comment: a fiddle with also the html would be helpful

Comment: @MattBall i just leave the field empty. I want it to only validate if the field has an entry, leaving the field empty is allowable in which case of course the function shouldn't validate it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but that does not answer my question. Try a `console.log(num2)` or use a breakpoint to see why the `num2 !== ""` check is `true` when you think it should be `false`.

Comment: @MattBall `!=` would work here. `!==` is an explicit (exactly equal to) in type and value comparison. Which if the value is undefined would not be the case. Undefined would equate to a falsy value but is not exactly equal to an empty string. This is why `if(num2)` or `if(num2 != "")` should both work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of num2 may be undefined if it's empty.

A better approach is probably:

`if (num2 && !num2.match(/\(\d{2}\)\d{8}/))`

Which will check that num2 is actually defined and not blank.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be `if (num2 == "" || !num2.match(/\(\d{2}\)\d{8}/))` ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The alert should only happen if the field is non-empty and does not match the regex.

Comment: Just change to `num2 != ""` or as Ed has put `num2` which just checks that `num2` is `truthy` (Same thing)